# how to get time difference between two events in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to look it up and I came accross a piece of code which I don't really understand.

```
<p>Count the number of milliseconds between the two click events on a paragraph </p>
<div>Click on the above paragraph</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lastt, tdiff;
    $("p").click(function(event){
        if(lastt){
            tdiff = event.timeStamp - lastt;
            $("div").append("Time since last event: " + tdiff + "<br>");
        }else{
            $("div").append("<br>Click again.<br>");
        }
        lastt = event.timeStamp;  
    });
});
```

My questions are the following:

1. what does `if(lastt)` mean? it is a variable so how could it be
   true/false?
2. how tdiff is calculated before `lastt` is assigned?
3. why last comes after if and else statements and not before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- what does if(lastt) mean?

The statement checks to see if the `lastt` variable is set or not. On the first click the value is `null` (a falsy value) and the function just adds a `p` element.

> it is a variable so how could it be true/false?

Variables can have boolean values. Why not? But here the point is not checking a boolean value. The `if` statement is used for checking whether the value is set or not, i.e. the `lastt` is not `null`. The timestamp is a number and any number that is not `0` is considered a truthy value in JavaScript.

> 2-how tdiff is calculated before lastt is assigned?

This is not actually happening. On the first click, the handler do no calculate anything.

> 3-why last comes after if and else statements and not before?

The existence of the `lastt` is required for checking diff of 2 timestamps. The new `lastt` is used in the next call of the handler, so setting it after the calculation is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In the given snippet, you are using jQuery to store last time & then finding the difference(from current time) to print.

To answer your question :

1. `if(lastt)` is used to check if `lastt` already has a value.
2. `tdiff` is calculated only once `lastt` is assigned.
3. `lastt` comes after if else to record the end of event time each time. (if it were put in the if-else, it would have to be put in both. )